# При выборе в QComboBox крашится приложение | Python, PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Код на *Python*, с использованием библиотеки *PyQt5*.
Хочу сделать функцию, при которой, отталкиваясь от выбора пользователя и его суточного расхода калорий выводятся советы.
Суточный расход калорий вводится в `lineEdit`

В `comboBox` четыре варианта выбора: *Ничего не хочу; Хочу похудеть; Хочу улучшить фигуру; Хочу набрать мыш. массу*.
Если пользователь ввёл верный суточный расход калорий (давайте сократим - СРК) и выбрал "Хочу похудеть" в `label` выводится совет - "Чтобы похудеть, надо понизить свой СРК до (СРК - 500) ккал; Если пользователь выбрал "Хочу улучшить фигуру" - "Чтобы улучшить фигуру, нужно больше тренироваться при том же СРК"; Если пользователь выбрал "Хочу набрать мыш. массу - "Чтобы набрать мышечную массу нужно повысить СРК до (СРК + 400) ккал".

Если пользователь выбрал "Ничего не хочу" ничего выводить не надо.

Если пользователь не ввёл какие-то данные или СРК > 14241 или СРК < 417 ничего выводить не нужно.

Начал писать код, вроде всё правильно, но при выборе пункта "Хочу похудеть" приложение крашится. Помогите решить проблему.

**main.py**

```
import re
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from first_project.project.design_project import Ui_MainWindow

MIN_EXP = 417
MAX_EXP = 14241

class WayToTheDream(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # настройки окна
        self.setWindowTitle('Way To The Dream!')
        self.setFixedSize(1010, 763)
        self.label.setText('Введите сут. расход ккал (округлите)')
        self.comboBox.addItem('Ничего не хочу')
        self.comboBox.addItem('Хочу похудеть')
        self.comboBox.addItem('Хочу улучшить фигуру')
        self.comboBox.addItem('Хочу набрать мыш. массу')

        self.comboBox.activated.connect(self.expenditure_advice)
        
        
    def checking_condition_exp(self):
        if MAX_EXP >= int(''.join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.lineEdit.text()))))) >= MIN_EXP:
            return int(''.join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.lineEdit.text())))))

    def expenditure_advice(self):
        if self.comboBox.currentText() == 'Хочу похудеть':
            self.label.setText('Чтобы похудеть нужно понизить свой суточный расход калорий до ', self.checking_condition_exp() - 500, ' ккал')
        else:
            self.label.setText('')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = WayToTheDream()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**design_project.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1010, 763)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #F0F0F0;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 510, 201, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 540, 201, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 620, 201, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1010, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите суточный расход калорий:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите цель:"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Получите советы короче"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Советы короче"))
```

Comment: Ошибка есть? Если да, то добавьте ее в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import re
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

#from first_project.project.design_project import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1010, 763)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #F0F0F0;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 510, 201, 40))    # (180, 510, 201, 16)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 550, 201, 20)) # (180, 540, 201, 20)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 620, 201, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1010, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите суточный расход калорий:"))
#?        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите цель:"))
#?        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Получите советы короче"))
#?        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Советы короче"))
        
        
MIN_EXP = 417
MAX_EXP = 14241

class WayToTheDream(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # настройки окна
        self.setWindowTitle('Way To The Dream!')
        self.setFixedSize(1010, 763)
        
        self.label.setText('Введите сут. расход ккал (округлите)')
        self.comboBox.addItem('Ничего не хочу')
        self.comboBox.addItem('Хочу похудеть')
        self.comboBox.addItem('Хочу улучшить фигуру')
        self.comboBox.addItem('Хочу набрать мыш. массу')

        self.comboBox.activated.connect(self.expenditure_advice)
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def checking_condition_exp(self):
        find_d = re.findall(r'\d+', self.lineEdit.text())
        if find_d:
            if MAX_EXP >= int(''.join(list(map(str, find_d)))) >= MIN_EXP:
                return int(''.join(list(map(str, find_d))))
#                return int(''.join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.lineEdit.text())))))
        return False

    def expenditure_advice(self):
        if self.comboBox.currentText() == 'Хочу похудеть':
            _condition_exp = self.checking_condition_exp()
            if _condition_exp:
                _condition_exp = _condition_exp - 500
                self.label.setText(
                    f'Чтобы похудеть нужно понизить свой суточный расход калорий до '
                    f'{_condition_exp} ккал'
                )
                self.label.setWordWrap(True)        
        else:
            self.label.setText('')
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = WayToTheDream()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]